# New InnovaSpa Storm HH Error Code

Tags: hot-tub

New hot tub giving HH[overheating code] error code. Water is 50 degrees F. See diagram. So far checked fuses and volts. When i unplug one of the sensors and plug back in the jets start but then it gives a HHand IC(ice detected) code which makes no sense. See digram[image]

Comment: Back up, pretend for a moment you don't have a clue what you're talking about (because we don't), and reread your question to see if you'd understand it. Then [edit] to clarify. What's a "innovaSpa Storm HH"? Is that a brand or a model? What's it do? Pictures of the wiring. Links to the installation manual. What does "Balboa components" mean and what's it have to do with anything?

Comment: It's a new spa. What did the manufacturer say when you contacted them? https://innovaspa.com/en_us/contact

Comment: Waiting on customer support. They are dragging their feet. Looking thru the contract to see if i can return it.